# Array search with CSV and php

Tags: php, csv, fopen

Hey all i am trying to search through a CSV file using the following code:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, "r");
$os = array(fgetcsv($fh));

if (in_array("12.56.102.44", $os)) {
    echo "Got it!";
}
```

The CSV is in this format:

```
"132.89.14.110","41.98.365.111","12.56.102.44","77.295.10.111",
```

However, that does not work so i am sure i am using it incorrectly...

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is the CSV sheet setup so that there are numerous lines, one IP to each line; or one line of numerous columns, one IP in each column?

Comment: one line of numbers, no breaks no returns and no columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) already returns an array.  You should be calling the function like this:

```
$os = fgetcsv($fh);
```

Putting the return value inside an array will make the value of `$os` the following:

```
array(array("132.89.14.110","41.98.365.111","12.56.102.44","77.295.10.111"))
```

If there are multiple lines in your file that you need to check,  you'll have to make use of a loop, for example:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, "r");
while(($os = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
    if (in_array("12.56.102.44", $os)) {
        echo "Got it!";
        break; // stop the loop, we're done
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Also should be pointed that fgetcsv parses _only 1 line_ of the csv file

Comment: So since fgetcsv returns an array then how do i go about looping that array and finding the ip? And by **multiple lines** do you mean "ip","ip",etc or a new line for each ip? Because running your code above provides no **Got it!** results.